# Доступ к файлу настроек для всех пользователей

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется конфигурационный файл Devices.xml, который хранит настройки подключаемого оборудования.
На текущий момент этот файл располагается в *C:\ProgramData[Имя приложения]\Devices.xml* (Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
Этот файл может меняться из приложения для любого пользователя ОС, но возникает проблема, что пользователь может запустить приложение в первый раз от имени администратора (просто в силу некоторых привычек) и тогда доступ к этому файлу будет только с правами администратора и пользователи которые попробуют в следующий раз изменить, что-либо в настройках оборудования войдя без таких прав получат исключение, так как доступ у них будет только для чтения.
Просить у пользователя права администратора для изменения настроек оборудования  совсем не хочется.
Другие файлы конфигурации хранятся уже не посредственно в папке пользователя (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) и там проблем уже с чтением\записью естественно не возникает.
Даже не знаю, как правильно задать вопрос, но что можно сделать, чтоб единственный файл был доступен для чтения\записи даже если вдруг запустили программу от имени администратора.
Как предположение при установке давать права полные на *C:\ProgramData[Имя приложения]* хотя мне кажется это не правильно.

Comment: Хранить настройки в txt-файлике к которому все имеют доступ на запись- это плохая идея, так как параллельная запись может его убить...

Comment: В данном случае его настраивает только "опытный пользователь" и его меняют не постоянно. То есть постоянной записи в него нет. Те файлы которые могут меняться сделаны под каждого пользователя ОС свои и хранятся в папке пользователя.
Оборудованием подключенное к ПК пользуются все пользователи ОС, в нашем случае не имеет смысла делать под каждого пользователя свой конфиг с оборудованием.

Comment: Вот тема близкая по моему вопросу:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107812/privileges-owner-issue-when-writing-in-c-programdata/22107884

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что это может считаться решением, но в итоге так и остановился на изменении прав доступа на папку при установке.
Для создания установщика использую InnoSetup и для назначения прав на папку *C:\ProgramData\[Имя приложения]* использую данный скрипт:

```
   [Dirs] 
   Name: "C:\ProgramData\[Имя приложения]"; Permissions: users-modify
```

**users-modify** При установке назначает права группе "Пользователи" на чтение\запись.

[Документация InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection)